# Function ending after while loop is finished

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

```
def stick():
    global randomCard
    global npc_final_score
    global user_final_score

    npc_final_score = int(npc_card[0]) + int(npc_card[1])
    user_final_score = int(user_card[0]) + int(user_card[1])
    print(f"The NPCs cards are {npc_final_score} ")

    if npc_final_score < 16:
        while npc_final_score < 16:
            # Generate another random number
            randomInt = random.randint(0, len(cards))
            randomCard = cards[randomInt - 1]
            npc_final_score += int(randomCard)
            print(f"The NPC drew a {randomCard}, their score is {npc_final_score}")
            if npc_final_score >= 16:
                break
            
    if npc_final_score > 21:
            print(f"You win!\n Your final score is {user_final_score}\n The NPC drew a {randomCard}, meaning they went bust with a final score of {npc_final_score}")
    elif npc_final_score == user_final_score:
            print(f"You draw!\n Your final score was{user_final_score} and the NPCs final score was also {npc_final_score}")
    else:
            (f"You lose!\n The NPC had a final score of {npc_final_score} while yours was {user_final_score}")
```

I'm quite new to coding so don't judge. The challenge is to make a blackjack game so I am making a function for if the player selects to stick with their cards. This function is suppose to generate the NPCs 2nd card. If the NPCs cards add up to less than 16 I want it to generate a new card. The code works as intended until the NPC has a score of 16 or over. At this point the function ends and the if statements at the bottom dosen't seem to run. Can someone explain why?

Comment: You probably need to print the last if statement `print(f"You lose! ...`

Comment: You should probably pass your variables into the function, rather than use globals as well: `def stick(randomCard, npc_final_score, user_final_score)`

Comment: You aren't handling the "Ace as 1 or 11" feature here.  If the dealer has A and 7, you don't want to hit.

Comment: Btw, the 2 "if npc_final_score < 16: " statements are not necessary; the while loop is enough.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. Anyway if you got an answer, what about answering your own question?